# node-couchdb can work in remote ? though couchdb in 3rd party server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchdb

I developed one application which connects to couchdb and done CRUD operations. For I have used [node-couchdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-couchdb) plugin. So, internally it is using smtp protocal. Now my question is If I host couchdb in some other server and If run nodejs file in my system, will it connect to that 3rd party server?

Any suggestions and explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean HTTP where you wrote SMTP (as that’s what CouchDB uses). Since HTTP is a networking protocol, it will work the way you describe. You only need the URL to the remote CouchDB and pass it into node-couchdb.